# Interior of a convex set

Tags: functional-analysis

How do I prove that the interior of a convex set $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex?

I have tried a proof by contradiction.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427721/interior-points-and-convexity

Comment: Saying that you tried a proof by contradiction is not very informative.  How did you go about trying to prove it?

Comment: Could you add more information?

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to prove this directly: If $a$ and $b$ are both in the interior of $C$, then $(1-t)a+tb$ is *also* in the interior of $C$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

To see this, consider that there are balls around $a$ and $b$ that are completely within $C$. Let $r$ be the radius of the *smallest* of these, and show that
$$ B_r((1-t)a+tb) \subseteq C $$
for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Can you complete the proof?